# Remote deploy WSP Files to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp

I create some WSP Files on a build server every night and would like to automatically deploy them to a QA Environment.

In SharePoint 2007, there was no way to remote deploy WSP Files except for ugly psexec-workarounds.

Has this improved with SharePoint 2010? Can I utilize the PowerShell stuff somehow?

My build server is not Part of the SharePoint farm. It doesn't even run the same SharePoint version (It runs a standalone Foundation, whereas the real farm runs Standard)

(Note: There are some questions on SO about this, but they are about WSSv3/SP2007 and don't apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved through through [PowerShell remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The WSP still needs to go to a server and Add-SPSolution et al needs to run on that machine, but I can now do that from the build server.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a post build event that run on our build server that copies the WSP file to our test server in  a specific directory. Once on the test server, a (Windows Server) timer job looks for the WSP file and a STSADM command installs them. Sometimes we run into issues removing the solution since I haven not found an easy/elegant way to check if the solution is properly removed. Usually I run a command to remove the solution. Run it a second time and then install.